# How can I capture an excel autofilter cell color criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I want to capture an excel autofilter cell color criteria but the codes attached do not work.
How can I workaround this problem?

```
Sub GetCellColorCriteria()
With ActiveSheet
 If .AutoFilterMode Then
    With .AutoFilter.Filters(1)
        If .On Then
           If .Operator = 8 Then  'cte xlFilterCellColor = 8
               c1 = .Criteria1     '<<<< this line generate an error;
               vprov2 = RGB(255, 0, 0)
               If .Criteria1 = vprov2 Then  '<<<< this line generate an error;
                   vprov = True
               End If
           End If
        End If
    End With
 End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please share error details and review [how-to-create-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Sub GetCellColorCriteria()
    Dim f, vprov
    With ActiveSheet
        If .AutoFilterMode Then
           Set f = .AutoFilter.Filters(1)
           If f.Count = 1 Then
               vprov = (f.Criteria1.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0))
           End If
        End If
    End With
    Debug.Print vprov
End Sub
```